# The following code is a java Arraylist code and I am unable to understand what is going wrong with it

Tags: java

My code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Scanner object.
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Creating ArrayList.
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //Creating index varibale to use as counter and keep track of inputs.
    int index = list.size() - 1;

    //Creating a loop to add user inputs in the list.
    while(true) {

        //Ask for user input.
        int user_input = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

        if(user_input == -1) {
            break;

        } else {

            list.add(user_input);
            index++;

        }
    }

    while(true) {
        //Asking the user for what number to search for in the elemnets.
        //Search for it in list and show its index as output.
        System.out.print("Search for ");
        int ask_user = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

        if(list.get(index) != ask_user) {

            index++;
            continue;

        } else {

            System.out.println(ask_user + " is at index " + index);
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Now whenever the userinput is like this :-

```
4

5

6

7

9

10

-1

Search for 10

Output :- 10 is at index 6
```

Sample input 2 :-

```
3

4

5

6

7

Search for 7

Output :- 7 is at index 4
```

This is running fine, but the problem arises when I type inputs like this.

Sample input 3 :-

```
33

22

55

-1

Search for 22

Search for 33


Output :- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)

        at IndexOf.main(IndexOf.java:40)
```

or

Sample input 4 :-

```
33

18

-127

90

-345

9

7

37

-1

Search for 9

Search for 9


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8

        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)

        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)

        at IndexOf.main(IndexOf.java:40)
```

What is going on?

I don't know what am I doing wrong, maybe it has something to do with storage, maybe int is not enough or something.

Help please.

Comment: IN the first of cases you were lucky to be searching for the last entered value.  As the `index` was still pointing at this value it worked.  What you really need to do is re-set index back to `0`

Comment: to reset add `index = 0;` to your code before the second loop

Answer (score 1):

Your index is not reset between your two loops, so the second loop will check the last element, then an element with one higher index than the last which does not exist, and throw an exception.

You are also asking for input on every iteration of the second loop, presumably the desired behaviour is to search the entire list for each input. I recommend looking into for-each loops for this to avoid the index issue altogether.